# "Self-explanation training"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, science

> Self-explanation is a learning technique in which students explain to themselves pieces of a learning material for the purpose of improving their understanding.

https://sites.google.com/site/unlvhowtolearn/self-explanation

https://www.lboro.ac.uk/departments/mec/research/mathematical-cognition/self-ex-training/

How can one convey 'self-explanation training' in French?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La traduction littérale ***auto-explication***, que je ne connaissais pas, est manifestement déjà utilisée :

https://blog.betterstudy.ch/5-techniques-efficaces-pour-apprendre

> 4-L’auto-explication
> C’est la production d’une explication de tout ce qui a été appris durant un cours. L’idée est d’employer des questions clés à l’instar de l’apport d’une expression ou d’un paragraphe comme information ou connaissance ou encore la liaison entre la nouvelle donnée et ce qui a été appris précédemment.

[http://www2.ift.ulaval.ca/~ericae/ift17586/e2003/speac.html#ae](http://www2.ift.ulaval.ca/%7Eericae/ift17586/e2003/speac.html#ae)

> Auto-explication
> L'auto-explication est une activité constructive. Nous considérons l'auto-explication comme une explication qu'un individu se donne à lui-même. D'une part, elle est bénéfique à l'apprentissage car elle permet de découvrir les limites de ses connaissances et éventuellement de les repousser. D'autre part, elle est bénéfique à l'apprentissage car elle peut être perçue comme la confrontation de son propre modèle mental, possiblement imparfait, à celui de la théorie à apprendre. L'étude d'exemple est propice à l'auto-explication. NOTE: Le terme "auto-explication" peut être considéré comme un verbe ou comme un nom (voir Chi, 2000), c'est-à-dire comme l'action d'auto-expliquer ou comme le produit de cette action.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this didactic method has not been exploited in this country, or, at least, not to a significant extent. So, there is probably no standard term.

What the English locution means (by definition only) would be in French "formation de l'étudiant au moyen du processus de  déduction personnelle que l'étudiant peut appliquer au sujet". Therefore a corresponding term in French could be "**formation par déduction personnelle**"; another term could be "**formation par auto-explication**".